# php array to xml using recurrsion

Tags: php

I would like my function to convert array of dimension N to xml, but it doesn't work.
Anyone can point me in the right direction?

```
function arrayToXml($array,$render = ""){
if(!is_array($array)){
    return $array;
}
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value)){
        $render .= '<' . $key . '>';
        arrayToXml($value,$render);
    }
    else {
        $render .= '<' . $key . '>';
        $render .= $value;
        $render .=  '</' . $key . '>';
    }
}
return $render;
```

}

Ok, I have found the solution:

```
function arrayToXml($array,$render = ""){
if(!is_array($array)){
    return $array;
}
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value)){
        $render .= '<' . $key . '>';
        $render = arrayToXml($value,$render);
        $render .=  '</' . $key . '>';
    }
    else {
        $render .= '<' . $key . '>';
        $render .= $value;
        $render .=  '</' . $key . '>';
    }
}
return $render;
```

}

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What does it do, what do you expect instead?

Comment: You UPDATE can't work, since you are overwriting `$render` if the child is an array…

Comment: @feeela, it's works for me, check it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the return value of `arrayToXml($value,$render);`, but you need to assign it to `$render` as well.

```
// …
if(is_array($value)){
    $render .= '<' . $key . '>';
    $render .= arrayToXml($value,$render);
}
```

Also note that tons of ready-to-use script can be found on the web to translate a PHP array into XML. For example http://snipplr.com/view/3491/.